# Integrating kafka in kylo

Tags: apache-nifi, kylo

[image]I am trying to integrate kafka in kylo using data ingest template available in nifi.
I am generating JSON files and have created a topic in kafka. And same has been configured in nifi's kafka-consume processor and added to the existing data ingest template. 
After creating a feed in kylo ,the flow is not going beyond the MergeContent processor and it is getting failed. And i am unable to see any errors in the kylo service logs as well.

Can anyone please give a solution to this problem.

[![Nifi Logs][kylo UI]][Kylo logs]

Comment: Are there any error messages in your nifi-app.log file? The Kylo sandbox has this file at /var/log/nifi/nifi-app.log.

Comment: I do not see any errors in nifi-app.log as well..

Comment: Even i tried with the a simple json file for ingestion. In step details i see that feeds do not go beyond MergeContent processor in Nifi

Comment: Is it not possible to ingest JSON data into kylo using the available data-ingest template?

Comment: Kylo's Data Ingest template works with the sample JSON files provided with Kylo. Could you add more information about what you changed and maybe a screenshot showing where it is failing in the flow?

Comment: I added a putFile processor after initialize feed in the standard ingest template. I am not able to see any records inside the uploaded file.

Comment: I have added the screen shots..Could you please provide any updates on this?

Comment: When the flow fails here it usually means that NiFi is unable to connect to Kylo. Could you double-check the properties for the Kylo Metadata Service controller service? Also, please search the nifi-app.log file again for any lines with ERROR or WARN.

Comment: Voted to close as it is unlikely to be resolved without additional input.